# Как в зависимости от выбранного ID записи в выпадающем списке обновлять поля ввода на странице?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, flask

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте.
Я разрабатываю веб-приложение на Flask с базой данных PostgreSQL.
Мне нужно написать форму для редактирования данных о городах БД PostgreSQL.
Есть выпадающий список select, который содержит ID городов.
В зависимости от выбранного ID должны обновляться поля ввода input, в которые должны помещаться текущие значение. А затем у пользователя будет возможность отредактировать их и нажать на кнопку "Сохранить".

Файл main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import psycopg2 as pg

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/db_menu/edit_delete_city', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def edit_delete_city():
    conn = pg.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                      port=5432,
                      user="postgres",
                      password="password",
                      database="database")
    conn.autocommit = True  # автоматическое сохранение
    if request.method == "POST":
        city = request.form['city']  # получаем данные по полю name
        country = request.form['country']
        photo = request.files['photo']  # получаем фото
        img = photo.read()  # читаем фото
        # Добавление в БД
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO city (name_city, country, photo) "
                           f"VALUES ('{city}', '{country}', {pg.Binary(img)});")
        conn.close()
        return redirect('/db_menu')  # возвращаемся в меню БД
    else:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT id_city, name_city, country, photo FROM city ORDER BY(id_city);")
            list_cities = cursor.fetchall()
        conn.close()
        return render_template('edit_delete_city.html', list_cities=list_cities, count_rows=len(list_cities))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Файл edit_delete_city.html

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" class="row needs-validation" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1 class="fs-3 display-4 fw-normal">Данные о городе</h1><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label for="select" class="form-label">Выберите ID города</label>
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="select">
                    {% for i in range(count_rows) %}
                    <option value="i">{{list_cities[i][0]}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <label for="city" class="form-label">Город</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Санкт-Петербург" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Пожалуйста, введите город
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <label for="country" class="form-label">Страна</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="country" name="country" placeholder="Россия" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Пожалуйста, введите страну
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Поле для выгрузки фото -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
                      crossorigin="anonymous">
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <label for="inputGroupFile01" class="form-label">Загрузите фото</label>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" name="photo">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Нажмите здесь для добавления
                            фото</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Поле для предпросмотра фото -->
                <div id="result" class="text-center mb-3"></div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Сохранить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

По похожим вопросам других людей, я узнал, что заполнение полей можно реализовать через JQuery и Ajax, но, к сожалению, я ещё не освоил это, поэтому прошу помощи.